# Android: how to create a background from pattern?

Tags: android, background, design-patterns

I have a pattern (.png image 4x4px) and have to fill the layout with it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

If I simply select the drawable as a background the image, it is stretched; instead it needs to be repeated along the x and y axis.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

[Here](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html) is a really nice explanation:

Put your "back.png" image on "drawable" folder. Then create a drawable "backrepeat.xml" like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

In your layout, add `android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat">

</LinearLayout>
```

As is the case with many Android good practices/handy tricks, it can be traced back to Romain Guy.

Comment: but for me it works only in the preview mode in android studio

Comment: how can I add rounded corners to a layout along with the repeating background?