# How to create texture/gradient background

Tags: android, user-interface, background

I wonder how can I create such a background in Android as shown on the image below:
[image]

I know how to create gradient background and I found out how to use patterns but how can I combine both of them?

Answer (score 1):

Check these out
http://mdswanson.com/blog/2012/01/30/repeating-background-textures-in-android.html

[Android: how to create a background from pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700099/android-how-to-create-a-background-from-pattern)

Comment: Both of these solutions shows how to create background using texture file. What I want is to combine texture with gradient. Is it possible at all?