# PopUp Window not updating database - Android

Tags: android, gridview, popup, android-gridview, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a kind of game using Android Studio. Till now I have done a gridview wich shows players stored in a database. I have had some problems with gridView.setOnItemClickListener, I have had to do it by putting the code into gridView's Adparter.class so if you know how I can do that into gridView's activity please tell me.

My problem now is that when you click on a player a popup window appears in which you could change the player's name or his genre. When you click on Confirm's button the database will automatically been updated, but it doesn't works. I have try to do it step by step by using Toast in order to know if it run that part or not, the problem could be the context, but maybe I'm crazy.

I left you some pics and the code related to it.

Gridview's pic -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO4ms.png

PopUp windos's pic -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAvcm.png

**gridView's adapter class**

```
package es.fingerlabs.gamecohol;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdaptadorAmigos extends BaseAdapter {

  private Context context;
  private ArrayList<Amigo> misAmigos = new ArrayList<Amigo>();

  public AdaptadorAmigos(ArrayList<Amigo> list, Context context) {
     this.misAmigos = list;
     this.context = context;
  }

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View gridView = convertView;
      if (gridView == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_amigo, null);
    }

    TextView TextoNombreJugador = (TextView)gridView.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreAmigo);
    TextoNombreJugador.setText(misAmigos.get(position).getNombre());

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    ImageButton deleteBtn = (ImageButton)gridView.findViewById(R.id.btEliminarAmigo);

    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do something
            AmigosSQLiteHelper amigosdbh = new AmigosSQLiteHelper(context, "DBAmigos", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = amigosdbh.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete("Amigos", "id_amigo="+misAmigos.get(position).getId(), null);
            misAmigos.remove(position); //or some other task
            //Eliminar de la base de datos **************
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    // ******* THIS IS WHAT I REFER TO PUT IT ON GRIDVIEW'S ACTIVITY *******

    gridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Id "+misAmigos.get(position).getId()+" Vidas "+misAmigos.get(position).getVidas(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, VistaAmigo.class);
            intent.putExtra("Id", (misAmigos.get(position).getId()));
            intent.putExtra("Nombre", (misAmigos.get(position)).getNombre());
            intent.putExtra("Genero", (misAmigos.get(position)).getGenero());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return misAmigos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

**gridView's class**

```
package es.fingerlabs.gamecohol;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SeleccionarAmigos extends AppCompatActivity {

   private ArrayList<Amigo> misAmigos;
   private GridView gridView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_amigos);
      gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvAmigos);
      refrescarLista();

    /* IF I PUT THAT HERE IT DOES NOTHING

       gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),misAmigos.get(position).getNombre(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/

    /*gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // get the data to pass to the activity based on the position clicked
            Intent intent = new Intent(SeleccionarAmigos.this, VistaAmigo.class);
            intent.putExtra("Id", (misAmigos.get(position).getId()));
            intent.putExtra("Nombre", (misAmigos.get(position)).getNombre());
            intent.putExtra("Genero", (misAmigos.get(position)).getGenero());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/

}

public void obtenerAmigos(){
    misAmigos = new ArrayList<Amigo>();
    AmigosSQLiteHelper amigosdbh = new AmigosSQLiteHelper(this, "DBAmigos", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = amigosdbh.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(" SELECT Id_amigo,Nombre,Genero FROM Amigos ", null);
    //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
        do {
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            String nombre= c.getString(1);
            String genero= c.getString(2);
            Amigo nuevoAmigo = new Amigo(nombre,genero,null);
            nuevoAmigo.setId(id);
            this.misAmigos.add(nuevoAmigo);
        } while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
}

public void refrescarLista(){
    obtenerAmigos();
    AdaptadorAmigos adapter = new AdaptadorAmigos(misAmigos, this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

**PopUp window class**

```
package es.fingerlabs.gamecohol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VistaAmigo extends Activity {

private int id;
private String nombre;
private String genero;

private EditText etNombre;
private EditText etGenero;
private Button btConfirmar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vistaamigo);

    etNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNombreVistaAmigo);
    etGenero = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGeneroVistaAmigo);
    btConfirmar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btConfirmarAmigo);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    i.getIntExtra("Id", id);
    nombre = i.getStringExtra("Nombre");
    genero = i.getStringExtra("Genero");

    etNombre.setHint(nombre);
    etGenero.setHint(genero);

    btConfirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AmigosSQLiteHelper amigosdbh = new AmigosSQLiteHelper(VistaAmigo.this, "DBAmigos", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = amigosdbh.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("nombre", etNombre.getText().toString());
            valores.put("genero", etGenero.getText().toString());
            db.update("Amigos", valores, "id_amigo="+id, null);
            Toast.makeText(VistaAmigo.this.getBaseContext(),"Nombre: "+etNombre.getText().toString()+" Genero: "+etGenero.getText().toString()+
            "Cambios realizados",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**gridView's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondogamecohol">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gvAmigos"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Gridview's item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white"
android:id="@+id/lyItemAmigo">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:id="@+id/ivFotoAmigo"
    android:background="#d8d8d8"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_tag_faces_white_36dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Chrisitan"
    android:id="@+id/tvNombreAmigo"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:id="@+id/lyBotonesAmigo"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btEditarAmigo"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_edit_black_18dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btEliminarAmigo"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_black_18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**PopUp window layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/PopUp1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Modificar amigo"
        android:id="@+id/tvModificarAmigo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#c9ed5a"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nombre: "
            android:id="@+id/tvNombreVistaAmigo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etNombreVistaAmigo"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:hint="Jugador 1"
            android:textColorHint="#333333"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvNombreVistaAmigo"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvNombreVistaAmigo"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Genero:"
            android:id="@+id/tvGeneroVistaAmigo"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvNombreVistaAmigo"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etGeneroVistaAmigo"
            android:hint="Hombre"
            android:textColorHint="#333333"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etNombreVistaAmigo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etNombreVistaAmigo"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Confirmar"
            android:id="@+id/btConfirmarAmigo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_green"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It´s ok to give us much information about your problem, but please post only a relevant part of your code, it´s too much to read

Comment: I've put so much information because maybe someone needs extra information in order to give a better answer, the most important part is the entry where I explain the problem.

Comment: :) ok, better than most newbies do with just adding one sentence :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I´ve seen in your code is, that you try to get the `id` from an `intent` in your `PopUp window class`. You have made one thing wrong:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.getIntExtra("Id", id);
```

it must be:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
id = i.getIntExtra("Id", id); //forgott id = here
```

and you should give a default value to `id` for example `id=-1` . The problem is, by updating your `database`, you give a `non value integer` and so it is not possible to update your table.

Comment: That works perfect, thank so much. But I have a doubt, why when I use a toas it does nothing? what I should put on context?                                                                                                           Toast.makeText(VistaAmigo.this.getBaseContext(),"Nombre: "+etNombre.getText().toString()+" Genero: "+etGenero.getText().toString()+
                "Cambios realizados",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

Comment: you have forgot to call .show() at the end of Your toast.... Toast.makeText(context,"HELLO",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I'm stupid, thanks so much!!. And finally If I want to refresh the gridview what I should do? I have my funtion to refresh in the gridview's class

Comment: usually call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and after that adapter.invalidateViews()....

Comment: I have solved it with a bit of trick, I have used a broadcast and in the other activity I listen for the broadcast

Comment: glad that it is fixed :)

Comment: one thing (has nothing to do with this question), how do You have made the yellow background in Your gridviews layout? Is it a full image? You can do some pattern (it´s like repeating small pictures), in that way you can save some space and get better performance than using big images....just only as a tip. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700099/android-how-to-create-a-background-from-pattern

Comment: I'm newbie and I have made a full image using photoshop, I will try to do it by pattern just like you have said, thanks a lot!